# Any way from a command line to change the DNS suffix of a Win7 PC?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-7, netsh

I need to change the DNS suffix on Win7 PC's. Netsh does lots,
but I can't find this in there. Any way to change it in a batch file (such
as a logon script)?

Comment: Do you want to change the actual DNS suffix, or the DNS **Search** Suffix?

Comment: You can do it with powershell and get-wmiobject, but need to know what value you are actually looking to change as MDMarra said.

Comment: You can also set it in DHCP options or GPOs.

Comment: I'm looking to check the "append parent suffixes of the primary DNS suffix" box

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/198231/append-dns-suffixes-via-windows-command-prompt.